# Adam Optimizer only returns one class every time

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, web, machine-learning, classification

I am currently creating a web application for image classification using Tensorflow.js. I realize that when I try to fit/train my model, the SGD Optimizer does its job well when predicting on the training set. On the other hand, the model trained by the Adam optimizer defaults to only one class/category even though there are 7 different classes in the oneHot encoded labels.

I have already tried lowering the learning rate many times, and it still returns the same results. Funny thing is, the loss continues to go down, even though its predictions on the training set stay the same. Why is it that only the SGD Optimizer works in this case?

The code below has been written in an async function that is executed when a "Train Model" button is pressed. The only difference in the code that yielded these two results was the optimizer used (everything else was the same).

```
//COMPILATION: minimize cross entropy between labels and model predictions
  model.compile({ //learningRate is a const
    optimizer: tf.train.sgd(learningRate), //This is the source of the problem
    loss: 'categoricalCrossentropy'
  });

  //I have defined a separate oneHot fn using the built-in method in tfjs
  let oneHotLabels = await oneHot(labelsCreator()); //tensor of oneHot labels corresponding to the training set images
  let images = document.querySelectorAll(".image[style='visibility: visible;']"); //all images that the model is trained on
  let imageTensors;
  await loadImages(images).then(response => {
    imageTensors = response; //promise returns an input tensor to the model (using tf.browser.fromPixels)
  });

  const config = {
    epochs: numSteps, //previously defined, number of steps the model should take
    shuffle: true,
    callbacks: {
      onEpochEnd: (num, logs) => {
        console.log('Step ' + num);
        model.predict(imageTensors).print();
      }
    }
  };
  model.fit(imageTensors, oneHotLabels, config);
};
```

RESULTS

```
Actual Labels:
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]

SGD Prediction (good accuracy):
[[0.7766488, 0.0011008, 0   , 0.1785417, 0.0128197, 0.0004938, 0.0303952],
     [0.0000667, 0.0000794, 0   , 0.0006806, 0.9991421, 0.0000079, 0.0000238],
     [0.0014632, 0.5784221, 0   , 0.1196582, 0.2930434, 0.0010978, 0.0063155],
     [0.0000067, 0.000024 , 0   , 0.0015023, 0.9984038, 0.0000043, 0.0000589],
     [0.0000328, 0.0000816, 0   , 0.0027291, 0.9970328, 0.0000105, 0.0001136],
     [0.0000657, 0.0000679, 0   , 0.0176743, 0.002068 , 0.000019 , 0.9801047],
     [0.0055083, 0.0023474, 1e-7, 0.7483685, 0.215641 , 0.0009718, 0.027163 ],
     [0.0045981, 0.0015817, 0   , 0.922437 , 0.026959 , 0.0002184, 0.044206 ]]

Adam Prediction (at every step since step 1):
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: please, if convenient, post the codes of your model.

Comment: Can you please add the complete model to the question along with the way you're setting the adam optimizer ?

Answer (score 0):

please explain more about your problem and your network. may be SGD is better method to train it and of course maybe you do not use proper parameter values for training network with Adam. first of all try smaller learning rates.

good luck!